# Hibernate sessionFactory.openSession() returns null

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, struts2, centos

I have a problem that my sessionFactory.openSession() returns null when i run it on the server. On the local machine everything is fine, but i dont know whats the problem on the server. (I even tried it with iptables off, so firewall is not it)

Local: All OK --> Win8, Tomcat 7.0.55, MySQL 5.6.20, JavaJDK1.7 
Server: NOT OK --> CentOS 6.5, Tomcat 6/7/8, MySql 5.1.73,  Java 1.7.0_71

I am using hibernate and Struts 2.
I have tried it now with Tomcat 6 - 8 but every time I am getting the same error..

**Stacktraces** 
`java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.XXX.util.SessionUtil.getSession(SessionUtil.java:15)`

The SessionUtil:

```java
package com.XXX.util;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import com.XXX.listener.HibernateListener;

public class SessionUtil {

    public static Session getSession(){
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
                 (SessionFactory) ServletActionContext.getServletContext()
                         .getAttribute(HibernateListener.KEY_NAME);
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

To initialize the Hibernate factory i use a Listener which is initialized on Startup in the web.xml.

HibernateListener:

```java
package com.XXX.listener;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateListener implements ServletContextListener{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HibernateListener.class);

    private Configuration config;
    private SessionFactory factory;
    private String path = "/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private static Class clazz = HibernateListener.class;

   public static final String KEY_NAME = clazz.getName();


    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        //
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

        try {

             URL url = HibernateListener.class.getResource(path);
             config = new Configuration().configure(url);
             factory = config.buildSessionFactory();

             //save the Hibernate session factory into serlvet context
             event.getServletContext().setAttribute(KEY_NAME, factory);

          } catch (Exception e) {
             logger.fatal("HibernateListener!!! Exception!!!", e);
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }

    }
}
```

and my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory >
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">PASSWORD</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XXX</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">USER</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>

  <!-- c3p0 -->
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">30</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">30</property>

  <!-- ========== Mappings ========== -->
    .
    .
    .
  <!-- ========== /Mappings ========== -->

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My suspicion is 
 1. SessionUtil is not able to find the HibernateListener
 2. There maybe a problem with the jar files. (all my jar files are in the WEBROOT -> WEB-INF -> LIB folder)

I just do not know what to do...

any help is strongly appreciated!
Thank you guys!

Comment: You can configure utility class to use static session factory, and update hibernate version.

Comment: Hey, Thanks man! That was the way in the right direction! I now have everything changed to a static variant and evola!

Answer (score 0):

Use basicStackHibernate interceptor in struts.xml because to access  Hibernate (Session and/or Transaction).

```
 <interceptor-ref name="defaultStackHibernate" />
```

May be it will use full for you